# How to share desktop screen from express.js running server with client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, puppeteer, chromium

I'm developing an application using express.js and **non**-headless puppeteer.

It's working well. But end-users can't see Chromium tab screen with running puppeteer automation.
The obvious reason is that Chromium is running on (express.js) server.

Currently, a javascript is working to send information to puppeteer on server-side and return a response to show it in index.html.

I'm looking for a solution to show Chromium screen in index.html. Maybe inside an iframe tag or something like that. *Remembering that Chromium is running on server-side.*

Basically I need to share Chromium screen with end-users.

Is it possible?

[Desire splitted index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykhFb.png)

Below, a simple express.js app that takes the name of the country on selected option in index.html and displays the respective capital. The capital screenshot is taken from chromium running puppeteer automation on server-side. I have no idea how to share chromium screen in index.html.

app
|_server.js
|_public
   |_index.html
   |_scraper.js
   |_styles.css

```
npm i express puppeteer
```

server.js

```
/**
* server.js
**/
const express = require('express');  
const app = express();  
const http = require('http').Server(app);    
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.static('public'));

// STARTING PUPPETEER NON-HEADLESS
var browser
(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
})();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname  + '/public'});
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let nation = req.body.nation;
    scrapeGoogle(nation)
    .then(capital => {
        res.status(200).json({ capital: capital });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.end()
    })
});


const scrapeGoogle = async (nation) => {
  
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://google.com');
    await page.type('input.gLFyf.gsfi', `capital of ${nation}`);
    await Promise.all([
        page.keyboard.press('Enter'),
        page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
    ]);
    await page.waitForSelector('#search');
    const element = await page.$('#search > div > div > div');
    let capital_base64 = await element.screenshot({ encoding: "base64" });
    await page.close();
    return Promise.resolve(capital_base64);
}

http.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Puppeteer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;">
    <label for="natio">What's the capital of: </label>
    <select id="nation">
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
        <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" id="go">Go</button>
    <div id="loader" style="text-align: center;" hidden></div>
    <div id="answer" hidden><img src="" alt="" id="image"></div>
    <script src="scraper.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

scraper.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    let button = document.getElementById("go");

    button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        document.getElementById('loader').hidden = false;
        document.getElementById("image").src = "";

        let nation = document.getElementById("nation").value;

        fetch('/', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ nation: nation })
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            let capitalBase64 = json.capital;
            document.getElementById("image").src = `data:image/png;base64, ${capitalBase64}`;
            document.getElementById('loader').hidden = true;
            document.getElementById('answer').hidden = false;
        })
        .catch(() => {
            alert('An error has occurred');
            document.getElementById('loader').hidden = true;
        })
    });
});
```

styles.css

```
#loader {
    border: 8px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 8px solid #3498db;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 32px;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
    }
}

#image {
    margin-top: 32px;
}
```